# In R Markdown is there an option for code evaluation that groups all of a code block together and then all of the outputs?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

For code blocks that output more than once R Markdown breaks the code block up with the output
eg.

````
```{r}
("one line")
("second line")
```
````

[image: rendered markdown of problem]

is there anyway to replicate the following output without having to duplicate the code block?

````
```{r, eval = FALSE}
("one line")
("second line")
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, collapse = TRUE}
("one line")
("second line")
```
````

[image: rendered image of ideal outcome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `results = "hold"` argument in the chunk options.

````
```{r, results = "hold"}
("one line")
("second line")
```
````

[image]